# Grails GORM where method not recognised by IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-orm

This is more of a minor annoyance than anything, but can anyone explain why IntelliJ (15 in my case) isn't able to find the `where` method for Domain objects? I am able to use dynamic finders with completion, but there `where` method never completes.

In the image below you can see that IntelliJ is happy with the findBy*, but has no idea on the where. This is also the case when trying to autocomplete method names.

[image: Find account by version two ways]

Debugging etc works fine, so it's working *somehow* internally.

Comment: try submitting the issue to intellij..

Comment: you must try intellij idea 15

Comment: This is my case as well, IntelliJ latest version (15.0.4) and all GORM methods (e.g. `.get`, `.list`, etc) are not recognized. Have you had any luck with getting an answer, maybe from IntelliJ team?

Comment: 2016.1 works for me, so I've been using the EAP version for a while. I'm using the final version now and it seems to be working fine. Not sure what will happen to IntelliJ 15 though.

Comment: For me, it doesnt work either on 2016.1. The module is grails-datastore-gorm-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar is included in the project and the file GormStaticApi.groovy in which the methods are defined is readable. But intellij does not recognize the methods.

Comment: According to the issue tracker, this is fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149568

Comment: Slightly less broken in Intellij 2016.2.2 release.  Where method is recognized. However, no domain properties are recognized within the where closure.

Comment: This works with the intellij idea 2016

Comment: Still broken in release 2017.1.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160166

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the docs, in the section [Using GORM for Hibernate Outside Grails](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#outsideGrails), have a nice TIP that works anywhere :)

```
import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity

@Entity
public MyClass implements GormEntity<MyClass> {
    // class code enter code here
}
```